# Unable to convert soap responce to json format in php

Tags: php, soap

I am  using one payment gateway  that  return response  as  `xml` and  I  am  trying  to  convert  to  `json`  buy  its  not  converting. I  have  tried that  `simplexamlloadfile` ,  `simplexmlsting`  function  and etc.

But  its  not  working.

**Code :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header />
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns2:SingleVaultResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST">
         <ns2:LookUpVaultResponse>
            <ns2:Status>
               <ns2:StatusName>Completed</ns2:StatusName>
               <ns2:PayVaultData>
                  <ns2:name>cardNumber</ns2:name>
                  <ns2:value>411111xxxxx1111</ns2:value>
               </ns2:PayVaultData>
               <ns2:PayVaultData>
                  <ns2:name>expDate</ns2:name>
                  <ns2:value>012025</ns2:value>
               </ns2:PayVaultData>
               <ns2:PaymentType>
                  <ns2:Method>CC</ns2:Method>
                  <ns2:Detail>Visa</ns2:Detail>
               </ns2:PaymentType>
            </ns2:Status>
         </ns2:LookUpVaultResponse>
      </ns2:SingleVaultResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Please post code here.

Comment: this is my responce      <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns2:SingleVaultResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.paygate.co.za/PayHOST"><ns2:LookUpVaultResponse><ns2:Status><ns2:StatusName>Completed</ns2:StatusName><ns2:PayVaultData><ns2:name>cardNumber</ns2:name><ns2:value>411111xxxxx1111</ns2:value></ns2:PayVaultData><ns2:PayVaultData></ns2:PaymentType></ns2:Status></ns2:LookUpVaultResponse></ns2:SingleVaultResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>  @ArshidKV

Comment: this  is  my  code      $xml = simplexml_load_string($soapClient->__getLastResponse());
         $json = json_encode($xml);
   $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);  @ArshidKV

Comment: Please check  `$soapClient->__getLastResponse()` it is correct or not ?

Comment: its  correct $soapClient->__getLastResponse()   because  its  returning  correct  response

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$string2 = 'your xml sting';

$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($string2);

echo "status => ".$doc->getElementsByTagName('Status')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```